# If series $\sum a_n$ is convergent with positive terms does $\sum \sin a_n$ also converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive terms such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
coverges, does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin a_n$$ also converge?

I believe that limit comparison test is necessary but I'm not sure how to use it here

Comment: Don't use the title's body and the question's body as one,   please. Type your question into the question body.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} a_k=0$, $$\tag 1\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\sin a_k}{a_k}=1$$

Thus $\sum_k |\sin a_k|$ converges $\iff \sum_k |a_k|=\sum_k a_k$ does. By your hypothesis and the above, $\sum_k \sin a_k$ will be absolutely convergent, so it will converge.

Comment: In the above limit would k be approaching infinity? I'm not quite sure how the limit equals 1

Comment: @Michael Recall that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$$ Yes, as $k\to\infty$; $a_k\to 0$. Since $\sin$ is continuous, $(1)$ above follows.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my stupid comment...+1.

Comment: @julien I'm curious! What did it say? =P

Comment: It said: what about $a_k=k\pi$? I had not read the very first line of your answer.

Comment: @julien Oh! I see.

Answer (score 7):

use that $|\sin(y)|\leq |y| $ (prove with the series) else you could prove it with mean value theorem.